# Ember.js / Konacha / Mocha.js test in promise

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, konacha

I've got some static data that I'm initializing into the ember app like this

```
App.initializer
  name:"Foo Data"

  initialize: ->
    store = DS.get("defaultStore")
    obj =
      [
        id: 1
        name: "whatever"
      ,
        id: 2
        name: "whenever"
      ]

    type = App.Foo
    store.loadMany(type,obj)
```

The following test seems to pass regardless of what 'whatever' is

```
it 'should be preloaded into store', ->
  Ember.run ->
    App.Foo.find(1).then((foo)->
      foo.get('name').should.equal('whatever')
    )
```

Is this a bug? What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I forget to check the obvious...

This

```
it 'should be preload into store', ->
  Ember.run => App.Foo.find(1).get('name').should.equal('whatever')
```

Works fine